# Make a div grow from bottom to top

Tags: css

If I wanted to increase the height from a div box then it increases towards the bottom. However, if I wanted to increase the height from bottom to top, what would be the ideal procedure?

One idea I had was to use `css rotate` to flip the div vertically, but is it possible without the use of css transforms? If so then how?

Comment: please share the code you have tried.

Comment: that's quite unclear and/or too broad; post the code and maybe a picture of the expected result please.

Comment: @web-tiki I assume you know how css rotates work xD. There is not much  to share.

Comment: You have to lock the position of the div first I'd assume. What is the purpose of this requirement?

Comment: @Asperger please don't assume anything, I might have no clue what css rotate is. And I have the feeling that rotating is no solution for you. So please share what you have tried as debuging code with no code is almost impossible.

Comment: @web-tiki https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/5vjcjods/

Answer (score 3):

You can insert your div in a "table cell" element (which can also be a div if defined accordingly with HTML & CSS) - and set its css `vertical-align:bottom`.

Try something like this:

**CSS**

```
.span
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tbl
{ display: table; }

.row
{ display: table-row; }

.col
{ display: table-cell; }

.pull-down
{ vertical-align: bottom; }

.box
{
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
}

.dbug
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    background:#BADA55 !important;
    border:1px solid #A00 !important;
    min-width:6px;
    min-height:6px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tbl span">
    <div class="row span">
        <div class="col span pull-down">
            <div class="box dbug"></div>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if you increase the height of the "box" div, its height will increase to the top.

Comment: The problem is the amount of div elements. There is a lot going on for achieving opposite results.

Comment: I get that, the problem is the box-model for table-cells; you only need a table-cell and it's `vertical-align:bottom`, then you can insert your growing div inside it and the results will manifest; however, to get a "table-cell" you need a minimum of 2, (or 3) elements. The styles & elements in the answer is for a "testable" solution, which is appropriate and will work.

Comment: @Asperger :: If the answer is not the solution you are looking for, then, update your question accordingly. If the answer is helpful or appropriate in some way (or not) then vote it accordingly. thanks

Comment: I voted up since it is a solution. I was thinking of using pseudo elements. It could works.

Answer (score 0):

To make the div expand upwards you can do the following:

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var p = 0;

function fn() {
    p += 1;
    x.style.height = p + "px";
    requestAnimationFrame(fn);
}

fn()
```

Here you can see that this only works if the position is absolute. Place it to the very bottom of a parent container and you will force the div to grow towards to the top.